# Android - Load video from private folder of app

Tags: android, android-videoview, audiovideoplayback

I have a problem that I have been trying to find a solution for a long time. My situation is as follows:

I have an app that downloads zipped videos and unzips them at the application's private folder and more specifically at a subfolder. For example at **/data/data/my.app.package.name.here/files/assets/assets-955.**

Inside this folder the video is unzipped. The unzipping process is completed successfully since I can pull and view the video without problems when running the app on the emulator.

I then have another activity that is accessing this folder, finds the video file and tries to open it. At this point I get an error that "Sorry, this video cannot be played" with the following error stack:

```
01-30 17:36:17.770: D/ContentDemoActivity(6757): File: /data/data/xxxx/files/assets/assets-955/bank_2.mp4
01-30 17:36:17.830: I/MediaPlayer(6757): prepareAsync called in state 4
01-30 17:36:17.830: E/MediaPlayer(6757): error (1, -2147483648)
01-30 17:36:17.860: E/MediaPlayer(6757): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-30 17:36:17.860: D/VideoView(6757): Error: 1,-2147483648
01-30 17:36:19.370: E/MediaPlayer(6757): stop called in state 0
01-30 17:36:19.370: E/MediaPlayer(6757): error (-38, 0)
01-30 17:36:19.370: W/MediaPlayer(6757): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
```

The code with which I am trying to play the video is pretty basic:

```
mView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

mView.requestFocus();
mHolder = mView.getHolder();

Log.d(tag, "Populating content. Assets path: " + mAssetsPath);
File f = new File(mAssetsPath);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
Log.d(tag, "File: " + files[0].toString());

mView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(files[0].toString()));

mView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

and the layout of the activity has a plain VideoView, nothing fancy there.

The strangest thing is that for testing purposes I used the same video, this time loading it from the "raw" folder and it runs smoothly without problem. In that case though I had to load it with:

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bank_2);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
mVideoView.start();
```

I would do the same with the downloaded videos but there doesn't seem to be any function at the API that will allow me to load a video Uri from the application's private folder.

I have found various solutions by using file descriptors, listeners for the videoView, flags indicating MODE_WORLD_READABLE, pre-calculation of the dimensions of the videoView, etc but none of them had positive results.

**In a nutshell, my questions are:**

- Why do I get those errors which according to what I have found online are errors that are related with problematic encoding of the video file ?
- What is the best things to use in my case, a VideoView or a surfaceView ?
- Which is the ideal method to load a video from the application's private folder and be able to play it?

Thanks.

### EDIT

After CommonsWare suggestion, I went with the following implementation:

```
File f = new File(mAssetsPath);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
Log.d(tag, "File: " + files[0].toString());

URI uri = URI.create("file://" + (files[0].toString()));
File file = new File(uri);
try {
    Log.d(tag, "1");
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcel = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE);
   Log.d(tag, "2");
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(parcel.getFileDescriptor());
    Log.d(tag, "3");
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    Log.d(tag, "4");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

 Log.d(tag, "5");
```

Unfortunately, this time I get the following errors:

```
01-31 12:40:11.480: D/ContentDemoActivity(15896): File: /data/data/com.houseofradon.meb/files/assets/assets-955/bank_2.mp4
01-31 12:40:11.480: D/ContentDemoActivity(15896): 1
01-31 12:40:11.480: D/ContentDemoActivity(15896): 2
01-31 12:40:11.500: D/ContentDemoActivity(15896): 3
01-31 12:40:11.500: E/MediaPlayer(15896): start called in state 2
01-31 12:40:11.500: E/MediaPlayer(15896): error (-38, 0)
01-31 12:40:11.500: D/ContentDemoActivity(15896): 4
01-31 12:40:11.500: D/ContentDemoActivity(15896): 5
01-31 12:40:11.530: E/MediaPlayer(15896): Error (-38,0)
```

So, something happens when the media player starts. Error code -38 doesn't seem to mean anything specific as I found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h).

Any idea what I am missing ???

### EDIT #2

I now use a mediaPlayer and a SurfaceView to do the whole process along with a surfaceHolder listener. Here is the code:

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
mHolder.addCallback(this);


public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    Log.d(tag, "surfaceChanged");

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mHolder);
        Log.d(tag, "7");
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        Log.d(tag, "8");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d(tag, "9");
}



public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(tag, "surfaceCreated");
    File f = new File(mAssetsPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    Log.d(tag, "File: " + files[0].toString());

    URI uri = URI.create("file://" + (files[0].toString()));
    File file = new File(uri);
    try {
        Log.d(tag, "1");
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcel = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE);
        Log.d(tag, "2");
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(parcel.getFileDescriptor());
        Log.d(tag, "3");
        mMediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
        Log.d(tag, "4");
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        Log.d(tag, "5");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d(tag, "6");
}
```

I can listen to the audio of the video but the picture is just a plain black color. I also get an error almost at the end of the video playback that says:

```
01-31 14:26:01.300: W/AudioSystem(17165): AudioFlinger server died!
01-31 14:26:01.300: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(17165): media server died
01-31 14:26:01.300: E/MediaPlayer(17165): error (100, 0)
01-31 14:26:01.300: E/MediaPlayer(17165): Error (100,0)
```

I am using an actual device, Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1. Any ideas ?

Comment: I have the same problem, could it help how you managed to play private video files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do I get those errors which according to what I have found online are errors that are related with problematic encoding of the video file ?

Because the media playback engine runs in its own process, and it does not have rights to read your file.

> What is the best things to use in my case, a VideoView or a surfaceView ?

A `VideoView` contains a `SurfaceView`. Whether you use `VideoView` or a combination of MediaPlayer and `SurfaceView` is up to you.

> Which is the ideal method to load a video from the application's private folder and be able to play it?

Either create a `ContentProvider` that can serve up your local file and use the provider `Uri` instead of the `Uri` to a local file, or create the local file using `openFileOutput()` and `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`.

Comment: So, I used your proposal and I now use a mediaPlayer and a SurfaceView. I also load the file "successfully" with the use of a ContentProvider. The problem now though is that all I see is a black screen while I can still hear the audio of the video. See my 2nd edit for the code that I am using.

Comment: @Sotiris: If you are testing on an emulator, that is what you will get, unless you have an extremely fast PC. The emulator cannot keep up with video playback. For video playback, I recommend testing on an actual Android device.

Comment: I finally found the solution. I was obviously missing a lot of things at my implementation, until I finally found the [example from Google] for Media Player of video files (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html) ... Lesson learned: Always search at the documentation samples. Thank you CommonsWare for your time.

Comment: @Sotiris would you mind to share the solution you've found? I am also facing the same problem :-/